# How to add the checkbox value temporary storage and put it in session obj using Struts 2

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2

**Hear is my checkbox:**

```jsp
<input type="checkbox" value="${subFill.fillingname}" 
name="fillings"> ${subFill.fillingname}</input>
```

**bean class:**

```java
public class AddCartBean {

public String fillings;

    public String getFillings() {
        return fillings;
    }

    public void setFillings(String fillings) {
        this.fillings = fillings;
        System.out.println("hiii"+fillings);
    }
}
```

**action class:**

```
public class CartAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,ModelDriven<AddCartBean>{

    AddCartBean acb = new AddCartBean();


    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        sessionObj=(SessionMap<String, Object>) map;
    }

    @Override
    public AddCartBean getModel() {
        return acb;
    }


 public String mycart(){


 sessionObj.put("fillings",acb.getFillings());
         System.out.println("fillings are....."+acb.getFillings());
         return "success";
    }
```

when first time I click checkbox and click submit button the checkbox
value is coming to my action I can store it in to session and get it
in my jsp but my question is that when second time I click another
checkbox and click the submit button that time my first submit 
checkbox value will gone and new check box value is coming, how can I
get the first submit check box value and second submit checkbox value?

Comment: AddCartBean should contain a Collection (eg. a List, or a Map), instead of a single value. Then you can put that in session, and populate / retrieve values through different names (or indexes) for different checkboxes

Comment: SessionMap will override the value when you try to insert the value with existing key...As @Andrea Ligios said you need to use Collection...

Comment: did you have any sample code can you please share

Comment: @goodyzain Or to manually add / remove tokens to the String like in the Nineties :D

Comment: @user2706147 http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `s:checkbox` tag when submitted it is set to boolean `true` by default. You can change this by providing `fieldValue` attribute of the `s:checkbox` tag.

See [example for `s:checkbox`](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/):

> In Struts 2 , you can use the `<s:checkbox>` tag to create a HTML check box. The `fieldValue=”true”` is the actual value that will be submitted by the check box.
>
> ```
> <s:checkbox name="checkMe" fieldValue="true" label="Check Me for testing"/>
> ```